# Number of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

You are given K prime numbers, bigger than 6, find the number of different number that can be made of those prime numbers(using 1 number, 2 numbers ..., k numbers).

Obviously you need to get the number of combiantions that you'll get using only 1 digit, 2 digits and so on and at the end add them all. It's easy, but when one or more digits appear more than once I encounter a problem.

Here's example:

You are given:

2 2 3 5 7 11 13

All the combinations are of two digits are: (2,2), (2,3), (2,5), (2,7), (2,11), (2,13), (3,5), (3,7), (3,11), (3,13), (5,7), (5,11), (5,13), (7,11), (7,13), (11,13).

There are 16 combinations, but using the formula for combinations i get 21, because it counts the (2,3), using the first 2 and (2,3) using the second 2 as different combinations.

I see a pattern there, that I need to find the number of combiantions and then subtract the number of combinations with the number that appear more than once and the prime number that are different of that number.. In this case there are 5 such combinations and 21-5=16, gives the right result.

But what when the number of same prime numbers is bigger?. For ex:

2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 7, 11, 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in that you are trying to count the number that can be made with 1 prime, 2 primes, 3 primes, etc. separately.  The computation becomes simple when you stop making this distinction.

In your example $2,2,2,3,3,5,7,7,11,13$, the number can have $0,1,2,$ or $3$ twos, $0,1,$ or $2$ threes, etc., so the total number of possible products is
$$
4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 - 1 = 287
$$
The $-1$ is to subtract the case of multiplying *no* primes together, i.e. the $1$ case.  Each possibility is unique by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.  And as long as you don't actually need the specific values for 2 primes, 3 primes, etc. this method is sufficient.